# error in R: arguments imply differing number of rows: 7, 6

Tags: r, bioconductor

this is what I typed into R

```
> sampleTable<-data.frame(sampleName=sampleFiles, fileName=sampleFiles, condition=sampleCondition)
```

It gave me this error

> Error in data.frame(sampleName = sampleFiles, fileName = sampleFiles, 
>   :    arguments imply differing number of rows: 7, 6

can somebody tell why it is giving this error? what does 7,6 mean? Thanks!

Comment: `length(sampleFiles)` and `length(sampleCondition)` are different

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments by HubertL:

> length(sampleFiles) and length(sampleCondition) are different

You should use arguments with the same length to build that data.frame